# freehand draw on map in arcgis for ios

Tags: arcgis

I'm making an app for ios using arcgis that lets the user freely draw (redlining) on the map by dragging their finger accross. I have tried using a sketch layer example provided by arcgis to implement this, but have had no luck. I also tried using opengl, but my drawing doesnt stay with the location it was drawn at. In simpler terms, what im trying to do is freehand draw on a map and when i pan and zoom the map, the drawing stays at its cooridantes on the map that it was drawn at, and stretches and shrinks based on zooming.

using an opengl view, i am able to draw. my problem is that i need to make the drawings stay at geological coordinates. here is my code for drawing. currently i am getting the touch coordinate of x and y on the screen, and need to change it to longitude and latitude on the map and then convert it to x and y on the screen. i am not sure how to do this.

```
    // Drawings a line onscreen based on where the user touches
    - (void) renderLineFromPoint:(CGPoint)start toPoint:(CGPoint)end
    {
         static GLfloat*     vertexBuffer = NULL;
         static NSUInteger   vertexMax = 64;
         NSUInteger vertexCount = 0, count, i;
         [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];
         glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, viewFramebuffer);

    // Convert locations from Points to Pixels
         CGFloat scale = self.contentScaleFactor;
         start.x *= scale;
         start.y *= scale;
         end.x *= scale;
         end.y *= scale;

    // Allocate vertex array buffer
         if(vertexBuffer == NULL)
         vertexBuffer = malloc(vertexMax * 2 * sizeof(GLfloat));

    // Add points to the buffer so there are drawing points every X pixels
         count = MAX(ceilf(sqrtf((end.x - start.x) * (end.x - start.x) + (end.y -start.y) * (end.y - start.y)) / kBrushPixelStep), 1);
         for(i = 0; i < count; ++i) 
         {
              if(vertexCount == vertexMax) 
              {
                   vertexMax = 2 * vertexMax;
                   vertexBuffer = realloc(vertexBuffer, vertexMax * 2 * sizeof GLfloat));
              }
              vertexBuffer[2 * vertexCount + 0] = start.x + (end.x - start.x) * ((GLfloat)i / (GLfloat)count);
              vertexBuffer[2 * vertexCount + 1] = start.y + (end.y - start.y) * ((GLfloat)i / (GLfloat)count);
              vertexCount += 1;
         }

    // Render the vertex array
         glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
         glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, vertexCount);

    // Display the buffer
         glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);
         [context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES];
    }

// Reads previously recorded points and draws them onscreen. This is the 
Shake Me message that appears when the application launches.
- (void) playback:(NSMutableArray*)recordedPaths
{
    NSData* data = [recordedPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    CGPoint* point = (CGPoint*)[data bytes];
    NSUInteger count = [data length] / sizeof(CGPoint), i;
    // Render the current path
    for(i = 0; i < count - 1; ++i, ++point)
        [self renderLineFromPoint:*point toPoint:*(point + 1)];
    // Render the next path after a short delay 
    [recordedPaths removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    if([recordedPaths count])
        [self performSelector:@selector(playback:) withObject:recordedPaths 
    afterDelay:0.01];
}

// Handles the start of a touchPaintingView.m 12-08-07 9:34 AM
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
     CGRect bounds = [self bounds];
     UITouch*    touch = [[event touchesForView:self] anyObject];
     firstTouch = YES;
     // Convert touch point from UIView referential to OpenGL one (upside-down flip)
     location = [touch locationInView:self];
     location.y = bounds.size.height - location.y;
}

// Handles the continuation of a touch.
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{  

     CGRect bounds = [self bounds];
     UITouch* touch = [[event touchesForView:self] anyObject];

     // Convert touch point from UIView referential to OpenGL one (upside-down flip)
     if (firstTouch) 
     {
         firstTouch = NO;
         previousLocation = [touch previousLocationInView:self];
         previousLocation.y = bounds.size.height - previousLocation.y;
     }
     else 
     {
         location = [touch locationInView:self];
         location.y = bounds.size.height - location.y;
         previousLocation = [touch previousLocationInView:self];
         previousLocation.y = bounds.size.height - previousLocation.y;
     }

     // Render the stroke
     [self renderLineFromPoint:previousLocation toPoint:location];
}

// Handles the end of a touch event when the touch is a tap.
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
     CGRect bounds = [self bounds];
     UITouch*    touch = [[event touchesForView:self] anyObject];
     if (firstTouch) 
     {
          firstTouch = NO;
          previousLocation = [touch previousLocationInView:self];
          previousLocation.y = bounds.size.height - previousLocation.y;
          [self renderLineFromPoint:previousLocation toPoint:location];
     }
}
```

Comment: Hello. Your question is quite unclear. What exactly do you want to know? Nobody here is going to write your app code for you. Please post some code and point out where you are stuck.

Comment: @RüdigerHanke added code. just need to know how to take coordinates from map as touch input, and use them to draw on my view, instead of taking touch coordinates of the screen and drawing form them.

Answer (score 1):

For this

"currently i am getting the touch coordinate of x and y on the screen, and need to change it to longitude and latitude on the map and then convert it to x and y on the screen. i am not sure how to do this."

I would suggest to save all the coordinates of the touch stroke in an array and then add these coordinates to an AGSPolyline. The way to do this is as follows

1. create CGPoint for each coordinate in your array.
2. transform the CGPoint to a AGSPoint using [self.mapview toMapPoint:CGPoint]
3. use addpointtopath method to add the points to the agspolyline